# What is the .NET equivalent of "ProducesResponseType" from Net Core?

Tags: .net, api, .net-core

I have to do a "backward" from an API made with NET CORE to .NET

I'm facing a problem changing `[ProducesResponseType]` from Net Core in a valid equivalent of .NET

I have for example this code:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "groupName")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(something), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
[HttpPost("thing", Name = "creatingThisThing")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostThing([FromBody]dynamic value)
        {
           /// Other Stuff
```

I understand I can avoid using the group name and I can adapt the route like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("", Name = "creatingThisThing")]
/// etc
```

But I'd like to know what can I use to "replace" the previously mentioned.

Hope I was clear enough.

Comment: this is defined in a [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/) which is compatible with full .net 4.7/4.8 as those .net version can consume .net standard 2.0 libs

Comment: @magicandre1981 So, can I use that Net Core nuget in my .Net project?

Comment: a .net standard 2.0 compatible .net framework can consume the lib. On [this page](https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProducesResponseTypeAttribute), you see the type is available for .net standard 2.0 via the nuget package. So always look at the API page to see if API is available

Comment: The attribute definition can for sure link to the framework assembly, the only question is how much good it does there. Framework Swashbuckle doesn't understand the core attributes, for instance. (Hint: https://mattfrear.com/2015/04/21/generating-swagger-example-responses-with-swashbuckle/ - use SwaggerResponse attributes instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `[ResponseType(typeof(SomeClass))]` from `System.Web.Http.Description` successfully with .NET 4.6.1.